# Angular 7 PWA not working Because of the Version?

Tags: angular, frontend, progressive-web-apps

Hey Everyone i try to make my Angular Application as a PWA. The Problem i have it just dont working. I try to do it with a new Projekt and some Times it workes and some times it don't. I think the Problem is some were that i have the Wrong Versions.

```
Package                           Version

-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.12.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.12.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.12.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.12.4
@angular-devkit/core              7.2.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.5
@angular/cdk                      7.3.3
@angular/cli                      7.3.5
@angular/compiler-cli             7.2.8
@angular/http                     2.4.10
@angular/material                 7.3.3
@angular/platform-server          6.1.10
@angular/pwa                      0.13.5
@ngtools/webpack                  7.2.4
@schematics/angular               7.3.5
@schematics/update                0.13.5
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.28.4
```

I followed this Tutorial:
https://dzone.com/articles/developing-pwa-using-angular-7#

I hope someone can help me i am Pretty new to the whole Angular Game.

Comment: why don't you just follow the original documentation (https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro)? What is exactly not working?

Comment: I don't have a Service Work

Comment: The article you linked in your question is full of Service Worker stuff. How could you have none?

Comment: That is the Question. Some were must be a bug or a mistake from my side.